# Is there an utility type to convert all elements in the tuple type to accept `undefined` in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there an utility type to convert all elements in the tuple type to accept `undefined`

Input

```
type InputType = [string, number]
```

Expected output

```
type OptionalInputType = [string|undefined, number|undefined]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mapped types on arrays and tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to produce new arrays and tuples.   That means you can define this:

```
type MapUnionWithUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | undefined };
```

And it will make the type you're looking for.

```
type OptionalInputType = MapUnionWithUndefined<InputType>;
// type OptionalInputType = [string | undefined, number | undefined]
```

Note that these are not truly "optional", since they still require the tuple to be of length two:

```
const okay: OptionalInputType = [undefined, undefined]; // okay
const boo: OptionalInputType = []; // error!
```

If you want to accept tuples of length 0, 1, or 2, you can just use the built-in [`Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type TrulyOptionalInputType = Partial<InputType>;
// type TrulyOptionalInputType = [(string | undefined)?, (number | undefined)?]

const nowOkay: TrulyOptionalInputType = []; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=64&pln=8&pc=63#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuaBeKBtAzsAJwEs4BzAGijkQFsAjCAgXQG4AoN0SKAWQEMwAVThEA9nADqRYAAthAEwgAzEhHkAeFAD4oWAN44A0lBJQA1hBCilUFEwBct7IaZQAPlERxFKuGqgAvuyc6FAA8mDAYnB8ADbwSKihWPxCIuJSsgrKqhoJyGiQWuwA9CVQXNARUeJx+UncWHiEJKTunt45fvKU1PSM7V4+uUwcAMbi+FCiZnwgjtXRdQgFyThDXWqUG75qrFBl07MgbBNwU3SioguRS-ErDZg4+4eMBKIEAIQcIdwoBIhYiBFrV7olCk8AAp8AhROLqeoQ4psQ6VWwAoEgmJg1aNHAACnwxDIg06u3kAEoAPyUfF9BgEUnDbrU0anSbAKiiADuYWOjn+gOBt1BiLW2Be5RmcyAA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, did not realize mapped utility types works for tuple as well like magic.